# Why `adaboost` using `gbm` package will not produce exact binary prediction values such as `{1,0}`?

Tags: r, boosting, cart, rpart, adaboost

My input data contains a response variable `is_disease` which is obviously a `Factor`(`Yes`,`No`). In order to use `gbm` package to perform a `adaboost` tree, I convert the {"yes","no"} to {1,0}. After I build a model

`model1 <- gbm(train, is_disease ~ .,distribution = "adaboost",n.trees = 50)`,

then I make a prediction

`p1 <- predict.gbm(m1, test, n.trees = 50,type = "response")`. I found that the predicted values is between [0,1],but most of the predicted values look like `0.04699193 0.05956444`. However, why it is not producing any predictions like exactly 0 or 1? Since as a classification problem, I need more binary values rather than floats between [0,1].

Comment: The decimal numbers can presumably be interpreted as probabilities of `is_disease`. [These are *much* better than hard classifications.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312124/1352) You can always compare them to some threshold to turn them into hard classifications, but I would recommend you think about your problem before you do so.

Comment: It does exactly what its documentation says.